# Using plural forms of nouns

Tags: plural-forms

When I say

> There are 100 kinds of ducks in this world.

should I use the ending **"s"** for  both "duck" and "kind" or just for one of them?

Comment: The sentence is correct if you mean grammar. But I would use the word *species* in this meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, *kinds* is plural and *duck* should be singular.  You can have one kind of duck, or several kinds of duck(s), however each kind is only one duck.

You will usually see the plural added to the noun, however, especially when the plural is irregular.  You will nearly always see the plural here:

> There are many kinds of people in the world.
>   There are several types of children in the class.

"There are many kinds of person in the world" sounds odd to most people, at least in the US.

Comment: What if I say "soccer is a kind of sport", should the word sport be in its plural form?

Comment: No, and no question about it either, since soccer is only *one* kind of sport.  If you were to say "Soccer is one of many kinds of sport(s)", then some (maybe most) people would use the plural "sports" and some wouldn't.